# How to upload a CSS file from inside a method?

Tags: css, javafx

This is my `Controller` class. I want load another css file from inside a method. I tried below codes but unluckly don't work. How do I to load up another CSS file?

```
@FXML
private Button mbut1;
@FXML
private void menubut1(ActionEvent event) {    
    mbut1.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("dinner.css").toExternalForm());`
```

Comment: Is `dinner.css` in the same package as the class from which you're showing the snippet of code? If not, what package are each of them in.

Answer (score 0):

You can import CSS from JavaFX in 3 ways:

Compiled JAR

```
String css = DynamicCSS.class.getResource("/jarcss.css").toExternalForm();
scene.getStylesheets().clear();
scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
```

File

```
File f = new File("filecss.css");
f.toURI().toString()
```

URL

```
scene.getStylesheets().clear();
scene.getStylesheets().add("http://www.jpedal.org/simon/dynamiccss/webcss.css");
```

Comment: For the file, use `f.toURI().toString()` instead of trying to construct the string form of the URL yourself.

Comment: Technically this is not importing the CSS in 3 ways, since you always use URLs. You just get the URL in different ways...

Answer (score -1):

```
File file = new File("C:/test.css");
scene.getStylesheets().add(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Above lines of code will upload css dynamically.

Comment: This won't work, since your "URL" is missing and important part: the **protocol**!!!

Comment: css is stored on local drive.what is need of "URL" here?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getStylesheets-- : *Gets an observable list of string **URLs** linking to the stylesheets [...]*

Comment: We can add css using local files also

Comment: Yes, but not the way you do it. I've tested this just to be sure and using the file correctly works, using it like this doesn't work.